# mpd crashes on database update

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, segmentation-fault, mpd

Mpd (latest version from repositories, Ubuntu 14.10) crashes when refreshing the database.
At first it crashed on every m4a file, even with the necessary libraries (libmad0) installed and up to date.
So I moved all m4a files out of my music directory and then it started crashing on certain mp3 files.
I noticed it always hangs on a file in a directory .AppleDouble, so I moved all these directories out of my music directory, but it seems they are recreated (does mpd do this ?).
Is mpd crashing on files already in the database ?

Anyway, everything I googled was more then 3 years old and about bugs in either ffmpeg, libav or libmad0... 
Either way, mpd shouldn't crash, but ignore the error and continue.

Here's the output of mpd (same as found on many bugreports about this)

```
update: reading unsorted/.AppleDouble/06 A volta.mp3
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0x00000000 at offset 737.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Hit end of (available) data during resync.
mpg123: mpg123_getformat() failed: Message: I am done with this track.
Segmentation fault
```

So if I remove this particular track (in this case *unsorted/.AppleDouble/06 A volta.mp3*) and make mpd update it's database, it will move on until there's another mp3 it crashes on...

Edit: I installed the latest version of mpg123 from sourceforge, with the same result...

Comment: I don't use a Mac, but it looks like the files in .AppleDouble contain metadata, not the actual music files, which explains MPD crashing. If you can find the program respawning that folder, maybe you can stop it, or change the location of you music directory. Are there other tracks causing it to crash? I once had a corrupted mp3 and until I deleted it, MPD wouldn't run properly (which, as you point out, is probably a bug as it should just declare an error and move on).

Comment: Crashes should be reported to the mpd bugs tracker: http://bugs.musicpd.org/my_view_page.php Reporting them on a Q/A website will not help with fixing the bugs.